# What's the best way to compile Ruby from source on 64-bit RedHat Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, 64-bit, makefile

On RedHat Enterprise Linux 5 the latest Ruby version available via RPM is 1.8.5.  My Rails app requires 1.8.6 or above so I need to compile Ruby from source.

I have tried the following to build it and it seems to build ok, but then I'm seeing gcc compilation errors when trying to run a plug-in which requires RubyInline.

There seems to be a lack of decent documentation for building Ruby from source, suitable for running Rails apps.

Here's how I compiled Ruby:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --with-openssl-include=/usr/include/openssl --with-openssl-lib=/usr/lib64/openssl/engines
make
sudo make install
```

I wonder whether there are specific compile flags I need to build this on a 64-bit system.  The actual error I'm seeing is

```
 error executing "gcc -shared   -fPIC -g -O2   -I /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux  -I /usr/include -L/usr/lib -o \"/home/deploy/.ruby_inline/Inline_ImageScience_aa58.so\" \"/home/deploy/.ruby_inline/Inline_ImageScience_aa58.c\" -lfreeimage -lstdc++ ":
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does it give any more in the way of error messages, as the one you quote doesn't really help with pinpointing the problem?

Comment: Shouldn't you pass -m64 to gcc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would probably be to just "steal" a Ruby 1.8.6 RPM from Fedora. The second best way would be to steal a Ruby 1.8.6 SRPM from Fedora and build it yourself.

However, there is one thing you could do: add a `--disable-pthread` flag to the `configure` line and remove `--enable-pthread` if it's there. `--enable-pthread` makes MRI *significantly* slower, and is only needed if you want to use Ruby/Tk and your system's Tk library was built with `--enable-pthread`.

Answer (score 0):

[Ruby packages for Fedora](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=125) (including SRPM)

Couldn't post as a comment on the correct answer so added here - editors feel free to tidy-up.